# Calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a complex dynamic matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a class that needs to use an Eigen Matrix as an instance variable.  Unfortunately I have more then one size so I think I am forced to use dynamic as the size parameter;

I declare the instance variable as:

```
Matrix<std::complex<float>, Dynamic, Dynamic> mCSM;
```

and in the constructor I fix the size with:

```
mCSM.resize(40, 40);
```

I look at the matrix in the debugger and it has the correct size so I think this is good.

I now want to get the Eigen Values and Eigen Vectors for the matrix and this is where I get lost.

I try

```
ComplexEigenSolver<Matrix<std::complex<float>, Dynamic, Dynamic>> ces;
ces.compute(mCSM);
```

and to get the eigen values and eigen vectors I use:

```
mEva = ces.eigenvalues();
mEve = ces.eigenvectors();
```

mEva and mEve are both instance variables and are built just like mCSM:

```
Matrix<std::complex<float>, Dynamic, Dynamic> mEve;
Matrix<std::complex<float>, Dynamic, 1> mEva;
//mEve.resize(40, 40);
//mEva.resize(40);
```

And after the call to `mEva = ces.eigenvalues();`  `mEva` has cols = 0 and rows = 0;

Do I somehow need to tell `ComplexEigenSolver` the `matrixSize`?  Is this the correct way when using dynamic matrices?

I now check if the call to compute was successful with:

```
ces.compute(mCSM);
if (ces.info() == Eigen::Success)
{
....
```

Comment: Did you check if `ces.compute(mCSM)` returns `Eigen::Success`?